# React native maps click pin to take you to another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently learning react native by building a mobile app for someone. 
The purpose of the app is to have a map view with pins and when you click on a pin to take you to another screen where you should view comments and be able to post comments. I am having problems with trying to click on the pic and make the page render another view. I tried using react navigator but nothing happens when I click on the pin. Any suggestions or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

This is the current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class SnapScene extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{
                latitude: 37.78825,
                longitude: -122.4324,
        }}
            title = 'Accident'>
                <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.container}>
                                      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
                                                title="Chat with Lucy"
                                            underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                                            <Text>We must go derper</Text>
                                      </TouchableHighlight>
                </MapView.Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SnapSceneApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: SnapScene },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have function for callout looking like this:

```
navigateToView(viewName:string) {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

  navigate(viewName);
}
```

Then just call it in callout:
`<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.navigateToView('Chat')}`

Comment: You're a lifesaver!